# What if I rebase git branch on itself?

Tags: git, github, branch, rebase

I think, I've just rebased a branch on itself and now it's kinda cycled (writing 'rebasing' for more than half an hour). How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl+C` to kill the git command if you're using a command prompt. If `Ctrl+C` doesn't help just close the app you used.

After that, go back to your git folder and check where you are and in the 'worst' case just abort the rebase with `git-rebase --abort`.

You can always also `git reset --hard` to get back to pre-rebase state.

Answer (score 0):

It's look like your are stuck in rebase mode but you didn't made a circular branch (don't worry).

The core concept of git is commit, and basics for commit is that one commit can only have one parent ( exception is initial commit which refer to nothing).

So inside a terminal when you do `git status` inside a terminal what is displayed on your screen ?
Following screen is a exemple of what `git status` should return if your are stuck in a rebase (don't mind branch and files ). what is important is the first line `You are currently rebasing branch`.

This is a good indicator of the situation and the terminal tell you just under this line what are your options.

Just follow the guide and `git rebase --abort` which will exit from current rebase and set your git repo to it's original state from before rebasing as if nothing happened

[image: something like this]

If you want to proceed with the rebase, fix possible unmerged files or resolve conflicts and commit changes then do `git rebase --continue`

GIT IS A TIME MACHINE FOR YOUR CODE so don't freak out if at any point you think you fucked up something after you `git reset --hard` or `git rebase`
`git reflog` will show your git actions history timeline with action hash (like a commit hash) and action description.

[image: git reflog]

Pick a action you want to go back to by copiyng the hash and use it with `git reset --hard <action hash you want to go back to>`. In my case i want to go back to the last commit i made before all the confusing stuff i did so i will wrote inside my terminal `git reset --hard 420d527` but be aware the `--hard` will erase all uncommited changes